# Problema no Login

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou tentando criar um Login básico, com verificação para que não tenha registros com mesmo usuários no banco de dados. Porém estou tendo erro nesta linha `$row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();`

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error:** Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in...

```
    $result = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha' ";
    $resulta = $conn->query($result);
    $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();

    if ($resulta->num_rows > 0) {  
        echo "<script>alert('Usuário Já Existente');</script>"; 
    } else {    
        $result = "INSERT INTO Cadastro (usuario, senha, nivel_acesso) VALUES ('$usuario', '$senha', '$nivel_acesso')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);      
    }
```

Alguém sabe como consertar isso para que haja a verificação do usuário antes de inserir no banco ?

Comment: A $query é inválida

Comment: não seria: $resulta->mysqli_fetch_assoc() ?

Comment: @AnthraxisBR também já fiz assim, mas nenhuma forma funciona. Queria verificar se já existe um nome de usuário registrado no banco, se sim alertar usuário e caso contrário inserir no banco... mas está dando erro

Comment: @AnthraxisBR, não. O cara tá usando o método orientado a objetos do mysqli. https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: $resulta é false @AnthraxisBR

Comment: @Sveen teria alguma outra forma lógica de fazer isso funcionar ?

Comment: if ($result->num_rows > 0) {   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  ..... tente fazer um while

Comment: O nome da tabela e dos campos estão corretos? Lembra que é case sensitive

Comment: @ArsomNolasco $result é false, não um objeto válido

Comment: tente com SELECT u.* FROM usuario u WHERE u.usuario LIKE '$usuario' AND u.senha LIKE '$senha'

Comment: usuario='{$usuario}' tente assim na senha tbm

Comment: Acho que o Mysql pode confudir o nome do campo "usuário", com a tabela "usuario"

Comment: O código postado funciona perfeitamente bem. Fiz teste no meu servidor. O problema pode estar na parte do código não postado.

Comment: @Victor testa minha resposta e me dar um retorno

Comment: É necessário postar código completo, conexão e estrutura da tabela para que alguém possa identificar o problema pois como comentei antes, o código postado funciona perfeitamente bem no meu servidor.

Comment: Só para ficar como observação, o código que tem está suscetivel a ataques de *mysql injection*. Algo a considerar mais à frente depois de resolver o problema.

Comment: O @LeoCaracciolo está certo. O problema, provavelmente, está relacionado à outra parte do código.

Comment: Obrigado a todos que ajudaram, eu desenvolvi o código rapidamente e estava passando do antigo PHP para o PHP 7, acabei me prendendo tanto que criei uma.condição de select para uma tabela diferente da desejada para o meu insert. O erro esta no select da tabela mesmo, deveria ser select * from Cadastro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está relacionado ao SQL.

Ao meu ver existe uma incoerencia na sua query. Me chamou a atençao que você verifica na tabela `usuário` se existe um registro e cadastra na tabela `Cadastro` esse registro que nao existe, sem adicionar um registro na tabela usuário.

Além disso a tabela `usuario` tem o mesmo nome do campo dela, e os mesmos campos da tabela `Cadastro`. Indicando que provavelmente houve uma pequena confusão nas nomenclaturas.

Sendo assim, acredito que o erro se encontra no nome da tabela da sua primeira query. Essa tabela `usuario` provavelmente nao existe:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha' ";
```

O certo seria `Cadastro`:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM Cadastro WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha' ";
```

Sei disso pois eu fiz o teste sem a tabela usuário e erro foi o mesmo:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()
>   on boolean in

Comment: O erro pode também acontecer se o nome do campo não for incorreto, ou qualquer erro de sintaxe

Comment: Sim @Sveen, porém, analisei pela incongruencia das informaçoes. Na primeira tabela o nome dela é o mesmo que o nome do campo, ou seja, usuario. A tabela cadastro me parece mais coerente pois as duas tabelas tem os mesmos campos escrito de forma igual. De qualquer forma foi editar a resposta para deixa-la mais genérica. Valeu pelo comentário.

Comment: @Sveen ve oque vc acha =)

Comment: Obrigado, fiquei tão preocupado em passar do PHP antigo para o PHP 7 que me prendo somente aos fetch, mysqli, as querys hahaha e nem vi que chamei a tabela diferente. E acredite eu estava tão correto quanto ao nome da tabela que fiquei 1 hora verificando tudo no código menos essas linhas que postei, não achava a solução e decidi postar aqui para ver se alguem achava o erro, eu sabia que estava nessas linhas mas não me dei conta kkkk obrigado

Comment: @Victor kkkk acontece. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Muda a forma de login, faz assim:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Cadastro` WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha' ";

if($con->query($query)->fetch_all()){
    //Usuário existe
    echo 'Existe';
 }else{
    //Usuário não existe
     $result = "INSERT INTO Cadastro (usuario, senha, nivel_acesso) VALUES ('$usuario', '$senha', '$nivel_acesso')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);  
 }
```

Comment: Mas $con->query($query) retorna false. leia a pergunta

Comment: Acho desnecessário fazer um fetch_all nesse caso visto que só é necessário verificar se 1 registro é encontrado

Comment: @Phiter o fetch_all traz só traz o encontrado, caso nada encontrado, ela já retorna  falso, fazendo com que não precise contar o número de linhas dps

Comment: É, considerando que o usuário e senha são únicos, faz sentido. Não sei qual é o mais rápido, o fetch_all ou o row_count.

Comment: @Sveen como retorna falso? Só se não existir o registro no db ou o sql esteja errado, caso contrario não retorna não

Comment: @Phiter se houver diferença na velocidade, acho que deve ser imperceptível, nesse caso ele ainda economiza linhas no código

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php. Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: @Sveen a falha é só no sql, mesmo que não exista nenhum registro ele ainda retorna verdadeiro por ter concluído a query

Comment: Então o problema dele é resolver o problema na query, e não deixar mais rápido economizando linha, entendeu?

Comment: @Sveen mas a query não tem erro, a menos que as variáveis não estejam recebendo o devido valor

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in.... Como vai executar um ->fetch_all() em um booleano?

Comment: @Sveen sim meu amigo, o que isso tem haver? Vc pelo menos testou oque coloquei aqui? Estou dando uma solução diferente da que ele quer, negative como quiser

Comment: Nem fui eu que negativei